# Android store and load Image from gallery

Tags: android, uri

I am currently allowing my user to pick an image from the gallery and I load it in an ImageView. Then I store in my sharedPreferences the URI of the image in order to be able to load it again later.

It won't work, and I've noticed that somehow the URI of the picture changed.

I was wondering how to simply store the Image I got from the gallery to be able to reload it later.

Comment: Copy image to your app storage and store its path in prefs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I store in my sharedPreferences the URI of the image in order to be able to load it again later.

That is not going to work. Not only might the `Uri` differ, but if the `Uri` has a `content` scheme, you lose the rights to work with the content identified by the `Uri` after your process ends. Plus, the user might get rid of the image.

> I was wondering how to simply store the Image I got from the gallery to be able to reload it later.

Use Java I/O to make a copy of the image to a file that you control (e.g., on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)), then use that copy. Adjust your UI to reflect this (e.g., use verbs like "import" instead of "link").

Depending on how you got that `Uri`, you might be able to call `takePersistableUriPermission()` to try to get long-term rights to the content, in which case the `Uri` also should be stable (assuming that the user does not move or delete the content in question).

Answer (score 0):

Better to store image path in shared preferences, then reload it again